# Insecure CSP value "'unsafe-eval'" in directive 'script-src'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

while trying to load a third-party js file into content scripts in chrome extension. I'm facing an `unsafe-eval` error

My **manifest.json** looks like this

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "host_permissions": ["https://mail.google.com/"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://mail.google.com/*"
            ],
            "js": ["3rdparty.js", "code.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

after loading I'm receiving this error

> Error logged: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript
> because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

so, I have tried adding csp to the manifest file

```
{
...,
"content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
  }
}
```

then I'm receiving this error in chrome telling that its unable to load the extension

> 'content_security_policy.extension_pages': Insecure CSP value
> "'unsafe-eval'" in directive 'script-src'.

Comment: The error message means you can't use unsafe-eval in MV3.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok , so how can i execute that script ?

Comment: Use ManifestV2.

Comment: Manifest v2 not supported if using Google login in Chrome Extensions. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/chrome-extension

 Any solutions?

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid **you cannot use `'unsafe-eval'`** in manifest version 3

> Are you executing remote code or arbitrary strings?
> You can no longer execute external logic using chrome.scripting.executeScript({code: '...'}), eval(), and new Function().

You have to move all your script into remote or local files.
You may generate scripts on a remote file (eg. php) and execute it using `chrome.scripting.executeScript` instead of using `eval()` or consider migrating back to MV2.

Comment: **Move scripts to local files** solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to embed twitter timelines (platform.twitter.com) which uses script element to load tweets, in content script?

Comment: what is "Move Script to local files"?

Comment: Pretty much you cannot link to external js files as dependencies. 

See this related answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777086/content-security-policy-extension-pages-insecure-csp-value-https-google-co